# Function of command vmware-vim-cmd vimsvc/connect

Tags: virtualization, vmware

Does anyone know the function of the command "vmware-vim-cmd vimsvc/connect (vimid)". I thought that after executing this command with correct virtual machine id, I will be connected to the shell of this virtual machine. But it only shows "already connected" and exits. Am I making some mistake in the syntax of command? Or the function of this command is completely different from what I have thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the VI Toolkit installed locally, but I did find this in the docs. Try:

```
vmware-vim-cmd help vimsvc/connect
```

It should show something like [this page](http://www.vi-toolkit.com/wiki/index.php/Vimsvc/connect). Since the valid products include vpxa and vpxd, I think this method is connecting to the host or vCenter rather than a guest console.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: I am also thinking the same, it is getting connected to host itself because after I execute the command it shows 'already connected'. But I am still not very clear about the entire picture and use of function like connecting to host from host itself.   I tried to find it out on VM KB but got nothing. Thank you for your help!! will update if I get any solution.